# Community Bot poking old questions

Tags: discussion, questions

The **community bot** modifies old unanswered question but the factors such as

- questionaire being inactive
- correct answer isn't accepted/ticked

Given these factors:

*What are we supposed to with  old questions being resurfed?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far as Stack Exchange is concerned, a [question is considered unanswered](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/09/30/ok-now-define-answered/) if:

- No answer has been marked as accepted

  **AND**
- No answer has a positive score

The Community bot will periodically bump any positively scored question that has an answer posted, but is still considered "unanswered" by the above criteria. So if you *do* see the correct answer on one of these bumped questions that deserves an upvote, upvote it.

Alternatively, post a better answer that might get itself upvoted quicker.

Comment: There should be a way that the mods can manually tick the correct answer so it doesn't reappear and doesn't effect the answered: unanswered ratio.

Comment: @AbduRahman That's unlikely to ever work out though since we shouldn't be assuming moderators have expertise in all topics to know the "correct" answer; no matter how well-learned they are, even the best scholars have their own areas of expertise and can't know _everything_ about _everything_ related to Islam. I'm pretty sure that sort of suggestion has been brought up on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com) multiple times by now and shot down every time.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what @goldPseudo has said, you can also prevent a question from being bumped by the bot by doing the following:

- closing the question (will only work if enough people close it)
- down voting the question (will work if it has a total score of -1 or less)
- down voting the answers to it if they do not properly answer the question

You should do this if the question is a duplicate or not properly answerable (e.g. if it lacks necessary details or wants personal advice).

> The Community user will bump **non-negatively scored**, **open questions** every hour that have **at least one answer scoring 0** and **none scoring more than that**.
>
> https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/701905